How to use beta function in modelica
When I define a calculation in modelica, I need to use the beta function, but I can't find the beta function in the library.
How can I use the beta function in modelica, or implement a beta function?
Thank you very much!
It would be best if there is a library that can be called directly. If not, I hope the implementation can be simpler.

Referring to the isobaric expansion coefficient beta?

Or  to the Euler integral of the first kind?

it is the Euler integral of the first kind

Such special math functions are not part of the Modelica Standard Library, but already available in the Modelica ecosystem by wrapping gsl_sf_beta of the GSL in Modelica-GNU_ScientificLibrary
This is a minimal Modelica example
model M
 Real B = GNU_ScientificLibrary.Functions.specfunc.beta_Bab(1, 2);
 annotation(uses(GNU_ScientificLibrary(version="1.0.0")));
end M;

